# Instantiating View in MVVM model without redundant observable calls?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room

I am using Android's Room database to handle my backend, and thus have defined a `Repository` class, that creates the database.  The `Database` class manages the `DAO`, initializes content, etc..

When my app loads, the `Main activity` observes changes in the View Model's `getAllData()` function, which returns it's copy of the Live variable.  While the database is getting initialized, the `View Model` requests for the data before it is done initializing.  Thus I have to add an observable to capture that data after-the-fact.

However, it takes about 2 `onChange()` calls for all the UI data to be present and the view to be initialized correctly.  (Data is empty on first `onChange()` call).

My issue with this is I can't observe it normally because that would essentially duplicate updates to the view.  (View sends updates -> database updates -> observable changes -> view gets "initialized" again).  Also, I wish to get rid of the smelly initialization code where the main activity tries to initialize view when the data isn't available yet.

Also to note here: using the observe once, when the data is cleared (through android settings), and the app boots up, the buttons appear blank, as the data obtained from the ViewModel is still empty at this point.  (Thus the extra observe needed).  I believe this is most likely due to the first onChange firing when the database is initially created, then secondly when data is inserted into the DB.

Any recommendations on how to get around these issues would be appreciated!

Here is a simple outline of the above in code:

View Model:

```java
Public class ViewModel extends AndroidViewMOdel {
    private Repository repo;
    private LiveData<List<Data>> allData;

    public ViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        
        repo = new Repository(application);  // the repo gets the DB instance -> DB builds database with callback to initialize data (if file not found)
        allData = repo.getAllData();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Data>> getAllData() { return allData; }

    public void update(Data data) { repo.update(data); }
}
```

Main Activity:

```java
protected void onCreate(...) {
    // ...

    //ViewModel.getAllTempos().observe(this, this::initializeData); <-- rather not do this
    Observer<List<Data>> observer = this::initializeData;
    observeOnce(ViewModel.getAllData(), observer); // <-- calls ObserveForever, then immediately removes the observer

    // Set View text -- this doesn't happen right away, and the data array is null at this point
    if (data.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            buttons[i].setText(Objects.requireNonNull(data.get(i)).number);
        }
    }

    // set listeners ... (Listener updates the model, which updates the entry in the db
}

// ...

public void initializeData(List<Data> data) {
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(data);
    // sort the data ...
    
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        buttons[i].setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", data.get(i).number));
    }
}
```

I have been curious if Transformations could help me here on the observable side, but not sure about cleaning up the initializing code in the `onCreate()` section.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided with using the `MediatorLiveData` Class to invalidate the observer so that redundant updating would not happen.  This means this observer is only really used for a couple (micro)-seconds on app start-up, but at least it shouldn't impact anything performance related.

**onCreate()**:

```java
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);
viewModel.getAllData().observe(this, this::setData);
```

**setData()**:

```java
public void setData(List<Data> data) {
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(data);
    Collections.sort(this.data, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.buttonID, o2.buttonID));

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        buttons[i].setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%d", data.get(i).tempo));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```java
public class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private Repository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Data>> dbAllData;
    private MediatorLiveData<List<Data>> allData;


    public ViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);

        repository = new Repository(application);
        dbAllData = repository.getAllData();

        allData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        allData.addSource(dbAllData, observedList -> {
            allData.setValue(observedList);

            if (Objects.requireNonNull(observedList).size() == 5) {
                allData.removeSource(dbAllData);
            }
        });
    }

    public MediatorLiveData<List<Data>> getAllData() { return allData; }

    public void update(Data data) { repository.update(data); }
}
```